# i cant understand the behavior of printf with recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I cant understand why my code output is `2,2,3` and also when I remove u++ it's output is `2,5,5` I am using code_block on windows 7 with gcc

I try to dry run my code but its output is different what I calculate

```
int f(int);
int u = 1;

int main()
{
    int n = 3;

    //scanf("%d", &n);

    f(n);

}

int f(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    else
        printf("  %d \n", f(n - 1));
    u++;
}
```

I expected `2,1,0` may be I am wrong but I cant understand why output is `2,2,3` and when I remove u++ it make big confusion for me

Comment: Indent your code properly

Comment: what do you think `printf("  %d \n",f(n-1));` is doing? what if i do something like `printf("  %d \n",n-1); return f(n-1);`

Comment: @Manpreet Sidhu The function has undefined behaviour because it returns nothing in case when n != 0.

Comment: There's undefined behavior in `f` in the case where `n` is not `0`, since it is falling off the end without returning anything.  This means that the caller will pick up a stray value for the function result.

Comment: The issue has nothing to d with the _"behaviour of `printf`"_ as suggested by the title - it has everything to do with the (undefined) behaviour of your code.  Did you ignore the compiler warning?  In VC++ it issues ` warning C4715: 'f': not all control paths return a value`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Let’s trace it through:

1. You call `f(3)`
2. `f(3)` calls `printf("%d", f(2))` - `f(2)` must be evaluated before `printf` is called
3. `f(2)` calls `printf("%d", f(1))` - `f(1)` must be evaluated before `printf` is called
4. `f(1)` calls `printf("%d", f(0))` - `f(0)` must be evaluated before `printf` is called
5. `f(0)` returns `2`
6. The `printf` call from step 4 is made with the result of `f(0)`, which is the value `2` - this is the first `2` in the output
7. `u` is incremented and now holds `2`
8. `f(1)` exits *without returning a value* - you’ve invoked undefined behavior here, and from now on *any* result is possible.  What’s likely happening is that the result of `u++` has been stored in the same register used to return values from a function.
9. The `printf` call from step 3 is made with the result of `f(1)`, which is undefined.
10. `u++` is incremented and now holds 3.
11. `f(2)` exits without returning a value.
12. The `printf` call from step 2 is made with result of `f(2)`, which is undefined.  Again, what’s likely happening is that the result of `u++` has been stored in the same register used to return values from a function.

This is why you saw a different result when you took out the `u++` statement.

**Note** - I say this is a *likely* explanation based on real behavior I have observed in the past; however, the key property of undefined behavior is that it is *undefined* - it doesn’t have to be consistent or repeatable.  The output could vary from run to run without rebuilding the code.  It’s possible that you’re seeing that output for a completely different reason.  The key takeaway is that there is an error in your code (not returning a value from `f` when `n > 0`) that needs to be fixed.

The question is, what is `f()` *supposed* to return when `n > 0`? Once you figure that out, add an explicit return for that value.  For example, if `f()` is supposed to return `n`, then you want something like

```
int f( int n )
{
  if ( n == 0 )
  {
    return 2;
  }

  /**
   * Don’t really need an "else" here
   */
  printf( " %d\n", f( n - 1 ));
  u++;
  return n;
}
```

You’ll also want to add a check that `n` is not less than `0`, otherwise your code will recurse until you hit `INT_MIN` and underflow, and guess what, the behavior on signed integer underflow (and overflow) is also undefined.

Comment: explaining UBs is wrong as it gives OP the false feeling of the predictability of the UBs.

Comment: @P__J__: Added a disclaimer - better?

Answer (score 1):

In the `n != 0` path, your function does not explicitly return a value, and the value returned will be undefined.

It is also not clear to me why you return 2 when `n==0` - you do nothing with this value, and it seems arbitrary.

Consider this:

```
int f( int n )
{
    if( n != 0 )
    {
        n-- ;
        printf( "  %d \n", n );
        n = f( n ) ;        
    }

    return n ;
}
```

It is both simpler (no `else` block), and has a single point of exit with an explicitly defined return value.

Answer (score -3):

Here is the solution:

```
int f(int);
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    f(n);
}

int f(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    else {
        printf("  %d \n", n-1);
        f(n - 1);
    }
}
```

You should avoid global variables and there is no need for variable u.

Comment: Still has the same undefined behaviour, but appears to  "work" by making `f()` rather then `printf()` the last function to be called before returning.  The global variable is not the issue here, and is most likely only a debug aid in any event - you should explain why your solution works or what was wrong with the original - but since you have the same error, you may not be able to.